# Wordpress advanced custom field query giving wrong results

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have the following code. It is supposed to return only the post from 'portfolio' custom post type where the format is 'print', the checkbox for 'welcome_gallery' is checked and the 'market' value is 'italy'. But it returns also other post not matching these key values.

```
    $recent_posts = array(
        'post_type'  => 'portfolio', 
        'numberposts' => 8,
        'orderby' => 'rand',
        'meta_query'     => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'meta_key'     => 'format',
                'meta_value'   => '%print%',
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ),
            array(
                'meta_key'     => 'welcome_gallery',
                'meta_value'   => '1',
                'compare' => '='
            ),
            array(
                'meta_key'     => 'market',
                'meta_value'   => '%italy%',
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
        )
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $recent_posts );
```

I've tried hard to make it work but it doesn't. Before I get crazy, is there someone who can help me to undestand the reason?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Typo? `'meta_value'   => '%print&',` Should be `'meta_value'   => '%print%',`

Comment: thank you, I corrected it but wasn't the problem...

Comment: These are standard ACF fields and not any of the special field types like repeaters that have a special syntax, correct?

Comment: they are ACF standard fields

Comment: Try removing the '%' entirely from the `meta_value` fields

Comment: it gives the same results, I also tried with `meta_compare` instead of `compare`...